# error TS2304: Cannot find name '_ZonePrivate'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular9, zone.js

I'm trying to test my angular 9 application but I'm getting an error when running with `ng serve`. It says it is running fine but when I try to display the page it says `Cannot GET /`. Also when I try to build it using `ng build` it displays the same error message without any useful information in the log.

```
ERROR in node_modules/zone.js/lib/browser/event-target-legacy.d.ts:9:67 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '_ZonePrivate'.

9 export declare function eventTargetLegacyPatch(_global: any, api: _ZonePrivate): boolean;
                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/zone.js/lib/browser/event-target-legacy.d.ts:10:54 - error TS2304: Cannot find name '_ZonePrivate'.

10 export declare function patchEvent(global: any, api: _ZonePrivate): void;
                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
  "@angular/cli": "^9.1.12",
  "@angular/common": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/core": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/forms": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/localize": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/router": "~9.1.12",
  "@angular/service-worker": "^9.1.12",
  "@types/showdown": "^1.9.3",
  "ace-builds": "^1.4.9",
  "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
  "material-icons": "^0.3.1",
  "ngx-showdown": "^5.1.0",
  "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
  "showdown-highlight": "^2.1.5",
  "tslib": "^1.10.0",
  "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.901.12",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.12",
  "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
  "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
  "karma": "~5.0.0",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
  "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
  "protractor": "~7.0.0",
  "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
  "tslint": "~6.1.0",
  "typescript": "~3.8.3"
}
```

If you need more information I'm more than happy to provide it.

Comment: Try upgrading your zone.js to a more recent version like 0.11.2

Comment: It has to do with zone.js, maybe another library "make noize", try to remove other "non angular library" one by one to see if it's working

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I deleted the following import from app-routing.module.ts:

```
import {patchCallbacks} from "zone.js/lib/browser/browser-util";
```

(Since it was unused anyway)

And that seems to have solved the problem.

No idea if this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

It might have happened if you have accidentally imported (maybe with IDE auto import) something from 'zone.js...' Just search for the string

```
from 'zone.js
```

or the string

```
from "zone.js
```

in your project and remove it (if it is not necessary).

Comment: Yes, thanks. I accidentally imported : `import {apply} from "zone.js/lib/browser/websocket";`